# Understanding why $T(X) = Y$ in a proof.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation

Here is the statement of the theorem:

[>[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxr0P.png)

The proof of this direction $(\Rightarrow)$ started with this statement "If $T(X)$ is closed, then its a Banach space with the norm inherited from $Y.$ Thus we may assume that $T(X) = Y.$  "

**But I do not understand why the previous statement will lead us to assume that $T(X) = Y.$ Could anyone explain this for me please? **

Comment: It might be more clearly worded as "Suppose, without loss of generality, that $T(X) = Y$."  Can you see why there is no loss of generality in assuming this?

Comment: No I can not see

Comment: @NateEldredge No I can not see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we prove the theorem under the additional assumption that $T(X) = Y$.  In other words, we would have proved:

> **Theorem 3a**.  Let $X,Z$ be Banach spaces and let $S \in \mathcal{L}(X,Z)$.  Suppose $S(X) = Z$.  Then $$\exists M > 0 \quad \forall y \in S(X) \quad \exists x \in X \quad S(x)=y\: \text{ and }\: \|x\|\le M \|y\|. \tag{4.1a}$$

Now to actually prove the forward direction of the original Theorem 3, suppose $X,Y$ are Banach spaces, $T \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$, and that $T(X)$ is closed.  Set $Z = T(X)$ and note this is a Banach space.  Let $S=T$, considered as an operator in $\mathcal{L}(X,Z)$; then $S(X) = T(X) = Z$.  So $X, Z, S$ satisfy the assumptions of Theorem 3a.  Hence $S$ satisfies (4.1a).  Now verify (it is completely trivial) that $T$ therefore satisfies (4.1).

In other words, since Theorem 3a with its additional assumption $S(X)  =Z$ could be used to immediately prove the original Theorem 3, there was no loss of generality in making that assumption.

Comment: Sorry about this question …. but does the meaning of $T(X)$ closed that it is surjective?

Comment: @Emptymind: No, "$T(X)$ is closed" means exactly what it says: the set $T(X)$, i.e. $\{T(x) : x \in X\}$, is a closed subset of $Y$ with respect to the norm topology.  Surjectivity is the statement that $T(X) = Y$.

Comment: I am sorry for my stupidness …. but still I am unable to verify this  "Now verify (it is completely trivial) that $T$ therefore satisfies (4.1)." …. could you please show it to me?

Comment: @Emptymind: Let $M$ be such that (4.1a) holds, and let $y \in T(X)$.  Then $y$ is also in $S(X)$ (since $S$ and $T$ are the same) and so there exists $x \in X$ such that $S(x)=y$ and $\|x\| \le M\|y\|$.  But $S(x) = T(x)$ so we also have $T(x) = y$ and therefore (4.1) holds.

Comment: But $S$ and $T$ are the same  considered as an operator in $\mathcal{L}(X,Z)$ only not in general.

Comment: @Emptymind: What I mean is that $T(X)$, $S(X)$, and $Z$ are all the same space (which happens to be a subspace of $Y$).